# mpi in c how to extends the use of MPI_Type_create_subarray?

Tags: c, mpi, large-data, hpc

How can I use the  **MPI_Type_create_subarray** to pass a arrays of characters but of very large size of type unsigned long long int
as the overall rows (total_nrows) = 31,613,582,882 and the number of rows to be written by each rank (real_rows3) around 2,580,689,006, in case using 14 ranks.

```
unsigned long long int globalsizes[2] = {total_nrows, 365};
unsigned long long int localsizes [2] = {real_rows3, 365};
unsigned long long int starts[2]      = {startrow, 0};
MPI_Datatype localarray;

 MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, globalsizes, localsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_CHAR, &localarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, you cannot.

From the MPI standard :

```
int MPI_Type_create_subarray(int ndims,
                           const int array_of_sizes[],
                           const int array_of_subsizes[],
                           const int array_of_starts[],
                           int order,
                           MPI_Datatype oldtype,
                           MPI_Datatype *newtype)
```

Arguments are `int` so there is an intrinsic limit of `2^31-1`.

That being said, you might be able to achieve a similar result by using an intermediate (and larger) datatype.
For example, an array of `2^32 MPI_CHAR` can be seen an array of `2^22` vectors of `2^10 MPI_CHAR`. That obviously does not work with any number, but that might help you.

An other option is to use [BigMPI](https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI).

Basically, `int` (32 bits) are replaced with `MPI_Count` (64 bits).
Keep in mind BigMPI is **not** part of the MPI 3.1 standard, so this is not an option if you have to write portable code.

**[edit]**

There is a chance BigMPI will land into the MPI standard, and possibly with MPI 4.0.

Comment: BigMPI isn’t part of MPI-3 but it is strictly compliant with MPI-3 and ISO C99 as far as I know, so it should be very portable (it is most likely limited by MPI implementations that are not _internally_ count-safe). I used the MIT license because I went everyone to be able to use it or copy from it with impunity.

Comment: Also, you should say it’s not in the MPI 3.1 standard, because there seems like a chance it will make it into 4.0 